# How to upload files from a react application to azure file share under storage account?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, azure, azure-files

I am trying to upload file from my local machine to azure file share under the storage account which I created through a react application. I'm able to follow the steps provided for creating a file and uploading here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/storage-file-share-readme?view=azure-node-latest

But can't upload file from my local machine.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written and the issues you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the Azure file then you can use the below code to upload any local file to  azure file share.

Enter your storage account name, SAS and a path pointing to local file in main().

```
// Create a share
const shareName = `newshare${new Date().getTime()}`;
const shareClient = serviceClient.getShareClient(shareName);
await shareClient.create();
console.log(`Create share ${shareName} successfully`);

// Create a directory
const directoryName = `newdirectory${new Date().getTime()}`;
const directoryClient = shareClient.getDirectoryClient(directoryName);
await directoryClient.create();
console.log(`Create directory ${directoryName} successfully`);

// Upload local file to Azure file parallelly
const fileName = "newfile" + new Date().getTime();
const fileClient = directoryClient.getFileClient(fileName);
const fileSize = fs.statSync(localFilePath).size;

// Parallel uploading with ShareFileClient.uploadFile() in Node.js runtime
// ShareFileClient.uploadFile() is only available in Node.js
await fileClient.uploadFile(localFilePath, {
rangeSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB range size
parallelism: 20, // 20 concurrency
onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev)
});
console.log("uploadFile success");
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajkumar. Also I want to keep track of progress of upload using onProgress in uploadData() method. But I'm getting progress only once i.e when the uploading is done. Can you suggest someother way?